# Contact form script not running, white page

Tags: php, html, css, forms, contacts

Getting a white screen when trying to submit my contact form which has these entries:
- Name
- Email
- Subject
- Message

Im attempting to recieve emails through my website. Ive checked all variable names and such and it seems that everything is correct. Im new to PHP so im a little cloudy on what to try next.
Thanks

```
<form method"POST" action="action/form-submit.php"> <!--NO FOR ATTRIBUTE, NOT ADDING FUNCTIONALITY-->
                <h2>Contact Me:</h2>
                  <label>Your Name:</label>
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name..." required/>
                  <label>Email:</label>
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..." required/>
                  <label>Query Type:</label>
                    <select id="qry" name="query" required>
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select:</option>
                      <option value="jobs">Jobs</option>
                      <option value="website">Website Issues</option>
                      <option value="info">Information</option>
                    </select>
                  <label>Your Message:</label>
                  <textarea name="info" placeholder="Your Message..." required></textarea>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>
```

Then the PHP code:

```
<?php
  $vname = $_POST['name'];
  $vemail = $_POST['email'];
  $vquery = $_POST['query'];
  $vmessage = $_POST['info'];

  $email_from = "test@gmail.com";

  $email_subject = "New Website Submission";

  $email_body = "Visitor Name: $vname.\n".
                  "Visitor Email: $vemail.\n".
                    "Visitor Subject: $vquery.\n".
                      "Visitor Message: $vmessage.\n";

  $to = "bradleyarcher98@gmail.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

  $headers .= "Reply-To: $vemail \r\n";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

  header("location: contact.html");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to see what is wrong, you need to turn on the PHP error handling.

When this is on, you won't just see a white page anymore, an error message with filename, line number and a message describing the error is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$vname = $_POST['name'];
$vemail = $_POST['email'];
$vquery = $_POST['query'];
$vmessage = $_POST['info'];

$subject = " YOUR MESSAGE Title ";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: "YOUR SITE NAME" . "\r\n";
$message = "
<!-- you can add CSS Aswell -->
<div>
<p>Visitor Name: ".$_POST['name']."<p>
<p>Visitor Email: ".$vemail."<p>
<p>Subject: ".$vquery."<p>
<p>Message :".$vmessage."<p>
</div>
";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```